# Webrtc,socket.io,Node.js: Cannot access server from different network

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ip, port, webrtc

I am trying to implement webrtc for video chat application. My application works only in local network. From different network (or ISP) i'm not able to access node js server or port.

server.js code

```
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    res.end("Hello World\n");
    fileServer.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8080);
```

Client side code

```
var socket = io.connect('http://my_ip:8080');
```

I would like to know how can I access it from a different network ?

Comment: Does your server have a public or private IP address? Is there any NAT transversal?

Comment: I have tried with both private and public ip... For NAT transversal i'm using google's stun & turn servers